# JSOUP count Total Elements in Map tag

Tags: java, html, spring, web-crawler, jsoup

Hi i am trying to make a web crawler using Java and for that i want to count the total number of section on the current page.The sections are in some areas tag contained in a Map tag. I am using Jsoup to get the tag but still have no luck.It keeps showing

My code:

```
    int totalSections=0;

    /*Page address for searching*/
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("sitename").get();

    /*Getting anchor tags*/
    Element area = doc.getElementsByTag("map");
    int total = area.childNodeSize();
    System.out.println(total);

    /*Looping through the page for total pages*/        
    for(Element aTag: area){
        System.out.println("inside");
        totalSections++;
        System.out.println(aTag.val());
    }

    System.out.println(totalSections);
```

Error generated:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)root cause
```

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

```
com.controller.CrawlerController.GetTotalSections(CrawlerController.java:126)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate over `Element` instead of `Elements`.

Replace:

```
Element area = doc.getElementsByTag("map");
int total = area.childNodeSize();
```

with:

```
Elements area = doc.getElementsByTag("map");
int total = 0;
for (Element singleArea : area) {
    total += singleArea.childNodeSize();
}
```